# VBScript - switching focus to window using AppActivate

Tags: vbscript

We have multiple TVs each connected to a different computer. The goal is to display/setfocus  on a continuous loop cycling through two applications. This has to be synchronized across all TVs. Originally i had set it up cycle through all the apps in the task bar by sending the alt+esc key. Which worked fine but had a hard time synchronizing it across all TVs. So i used the AppActivate to setfocus and switch between windows based on even/odd minute. It is now synchronized, but the screen seems to try to setfocus to the window every second therby causing the screen to flicker all the time. How can i avoid it??? Any suggestions???
Here is the part of the code.

```
' Loop lasts 1 second

intSleep = 1000

Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'repeat process indefinetly

Do while infiniteloop=0
    a = minute(time())
    intResult = a Mod 2  ' to check for even/odd minute

    If intResult = 0 Then
        'display window1
       if wshShell.AppActivate "Display - [Dashboard]" = false then
            wshShell.AppActivate "Display - [Dashboard]"
       end if

    ElseIf intResult = 1 Then
        'display window2
        if wshShell.AppActivate "Display - [TEST]" = false then
            wshShell.AppActivate "Display - [TEST]" 
       end if

    End If
    Wscript.Sleep intSleep

Loop
```

Answer (score 3):

It flickers every second because the variable `intResult` equals `0` for the entire even minute.  What you need is another variable, like `"intLastResult"`.

At the end of your loop, you would set `intLastResult=intResult`, and re-do your IF statements for changing focus so they only execute when the current result differs from the previous result.

I.E. `"If intResult=0 AND intLastResult=1 Then" or "If intResult=1 AND intLastResult=0 Then"`

This way they should only fire once per minute.

Comment: Maybe provide some pseudocode would help explain your solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's not really an elegant way to do this with VBScript, but you're right to move away from SendKeys.

I would simply increase the sleep time to 1 minute. That way you're minimizing the number of times it evaluates the If statements (thereby increasing performance). And it only tries to steal focus once a minute:

```
Option Explicit

Dim shl

Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do
  If (Minute(Time()) Mod 2) = 0 Then
    shl.AppActivate "Program One"
  Else
    shl.AppActivate "Program Two"
  End If

  WScript.Sleep (1000 * 60)
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks much for the suggestion! Yes increasing the sleep minute, minimizes the # of evaluations but the machines are not synchronized as the script file are started at different times on each PC. Is there a way to check if the window is active ??

Comment: I also thought inspecting the current active window would be useful for this but it doesn't seem possible. If you need synchronization, why not schedule a task to run the script at the same time on each machine, and then make sure the computer's clocks are set to get time from the internet

Comment: yes i will try that..looks like there's not much option left with vb script.. thanks again.