# How to generate key strokes from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I want to create a batch file to do the following:

- Start selenium server(webdriver-manager start)
- Run Protractor tests(protractor conf.js)
- Stop Selenium server()

This needs 2 different command prompts since webdriver-manager start will keep running and simultaneously the tests need to be executed

I have achieved the following so far. I have created a .bat file with the following contents:

```
start runTests.cmd
webdriver-manager start
Ctrl-C(**DOES NOT WORK**)
```

However, I am not able to figure out a way to shutdown the Selenium server(which is achieved by pressing Ctrl+C on the same window on which the webdriver-manager start command is executed)

Comment: I have created a cmd file with the following contents:

    start start_webdriver.cmd
    start runTests.cmd


However, to shutdown the server, the command Ctrl+C, needs to be executed on the window on which the server was started.

Comment: May I suggest that you edit your question?  Please make sure that there is an actual question in there, as well as the details of what you've tried so far.  You'll find then that your question gets more attention and is less likely to be marked down.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Hope the question is clearer now!

Comment: So, would you say your problem actually is how to shut down the server, having run it from a batch file?  If so, have you considered other solutions, apart from send a Ctrl+C to the window?  What about killing the process?

Comment: I checked that too. But killing the process is not a very clean solution. I want to knwo if there is some built-in mechanism in batch files to send Ctrl+C commands. OR some other better alternative to shutdown the webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate keystrokes using VB Script, which can be called from a batch file.

I followed this post: http://www.w7forums.com/threads/f5-key-via-batch-file.18046/, substituting {F5} with ^{C} for Ctrl+C.    So my file looks like:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.SendKeys "^{C}"
```

You need to save this file with a ".vbs" extension.

I also found from this answer [VBScript - switching focus to window using AppActivate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385843/vbscript-switching-focus-to-window-using-appactivate) how to set the focus to another window (which you know the title of).  Doing this first, you can direct your keystroke to the appropriate window, so:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.AppActivate "Untitled - Notepad"
objShell.SendKeys "^{C}"
```

I experimented with an empty instance of Notepad, so you'll need to change the window title string appropriately.  (Ctrl+C doesn't do anything in Notepad, but Alt+F4 closes it, so I used "%{F4}" to test it.)

Then you can simply call the VBS file from your batch file to run it.

Comment: Thanks Ian. So, using VB script seems to be the solution as batch file does not provide any native support for sending keys like Ctrl+C

Comment: Yep.  Thanks to you too - I've discovered something I wasn't aware of either!  It would be a good idea to edit the title of the question to describe the problem more accurately, then others will more easily find the solution to the problem.